# How to do a tabulation char in VBA?

Tags: vba, text

If you want to make a tabulation for a message box or to write in a file.

To write in a file:

```
> 'file 
> Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject 'FSO 
> Dim File_DBC 'file to write
> 
> File_DBC="" 'complete path
> 
> Set File_DBC = FSO.OpenTextFile(File_DBC, ForWriting, True,TristateUseDefault) 'open 
> Data File_DBC.WriteLine 'test'
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `vbTab`

> MsgBox "blabla" + vbTab + "blabla"

You can also use: `Chr(9)` which directly correspond to the tabulation char in the ASCII table.
I.E. : "reverse" of `Chr()` is `Asc()`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small contribution for the topic "Tabulator in cells", if this should be of interest to anyone. The code formats the range as a proportional font. Then it replaces (A) the first two spaces found in a line inside a cell or (B) replaces chr(9) i.e. the code for a tab character with several spaces. It looks like a wide tabulation. Here are three sub-modules that are placed in a module:

```
Option Explicit
'

Sub FormatList()

'================================================================================
'copy  some text from your folder
'paste into a sheet of this workbook
'run this procedure to format the list
'
'comment:
'at least two blank spaces will be detected to change them to a tabulator replacement
'the tabulator is set at character number 30
'================================================================================

'variables
Dim wks             As Worksheet:         Set wks = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
Dim iRow            As Integer
Dim iLastRow        As Integer
Dim rgV             As Range
Dim rgPreDatas      As Range                                                      'range of datas before changing rows
Dim rgPostDatas     As Range                                                      'range of datas after changing rows
Dim i               As Long
Dim n               As Long
Dim iRowsInCell     As Long                                                       'counter which represents the number of lines in one (1) cell
Dim sV              As String                                                     'string with arbitrary variables
Dim sSpace          As String:            sSpace = Space(2)                       'at least two blank spaces will be detected to change them to a tabulator replacement
Dim blnTesting      As Boolean:           blnTesting = False                      'set true while testing

'--------------------------------------------------------------------
'Pre
'--------------------------------------------------------------------

'delete columns
Call DeleteColumns                                                                'skip if not needed

'format wks
With rgPreDatas
  .VerticalAlignment = xlTop
  .Hyperlinks.Delete
  With .Font
    .Name = "Aptos Mono"                                                          'proportional font is required !
    .Size = 8
  End With
End With

'format headline
With wks.Range("1:1")
  .Font.Bold = True
  .Interior.Color = RGB(213, 213, 213)
  .BorderAround Color:=RGB(127, 127, 127)
End With

'setting
Set rgPreDatas = wks.UsedRange                                                    'select your choice of range
iLastRow = rgPreDatas.Rows.Count - 1

'--------------------------------------------------------------------
'Main
'--------------------------------------------------------------------
For i = iLastRow To 1 Step -1
  'do something if necessary
Next

'----------------------------------
'newline
'----------------------------------
Set rgPostDatas = wks.UsedRange
On Error Resume Next
  For i = 2 To rgPostDatas.Rows.Count - 1
    
    'pick each cell / replace some characters
    Set rgV = rgPostDatas.Cells(i, 1)                                             'change '1' which represents the column to your coumn to be changed
    If blnTesting Then rgV.Select Else Debug.Print i
    sV = rgV.Value
    sV = Replace(sV, "»", vbNewLine)                                              'if you want to replace other characters then add them here in a new line / this here is my choice
    sV = Replace(sV, vbTab, sSpace)
    iRowsInCell = UBound(Split(sV, vbLf)) + 1
    
    If iRowsInCell > 1 Then
      If Not Right(sV, 1) = vbLf Or Not Right(sV, 1) = vbCr Then
        sV = sV & vbNewLine & " "
      End If
      rgV.Value = sV
    End If
    
  Next
On Error GoTo 0

'----------------------------------
'format columns
'----------------------------------
With wks
  With .Columns("A:A")                                                            'format columns here or skip if not necessary
    .Font.Bold = True
    .ColumnWidth = 10
  End With
  With .Columns("B:B")
    .ColumnWidth = 50
  End With
  With .Columns("C:C")
    .ColumnWidth = 100
    .WrapText = True
  End With
  
  .Cells.NumberFormat = "@"                                                       'format the cell as 'text'
  
End With

'----------------------------------
'Tabulations
'----------------------------------
Call SetTabulation

'CleanUp
Set wks = Nothing
Set rgV = Nothing
Set rgPreDatas = Nothing
Set rgPostDatas = Nothing

End Sub

Sub DeleteColumns()

'===============================================================================
'Delete columns not of interest
'===============================================================================

'variables
Dim wks             As Worksheet:         Set wks = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

'Main
With Union(wks.Columns("F:Q"), wks.Columns("S:U"))                                'select your choice of ranges
  .Select                                                                         'make visible, just to be sure
  .Delete
End With

'CleanUp
Set wks = Nothing

End Sub

Sub SetTabulation()

'===============================================================================
'set space instead of tabulator
'remember: at least 2 spaces causes an enlargement of space
'===============================================================================

'variables
Dim wks             As Worksheet:         Set wks = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
Dim rgPostDatas     As Range
Dim C               As Range
Dim iFillSpace      As Long
Dim iLastRow        As Long
Dim iCellRows       As Long
Dim iFoundSpaces    As Long
Dim sSpace          As String:            sSpace = Space(2)
Dim iTab            As String:            iTab = 30                             'the quasi tabulator is set at character number 30
Dim sV              As String
Dim sArr()          As String
Dim i               As Long
Dim j               As Long
Dim k               As Long
Dim m               As Long
Dim lastRow         As Long
Dim lastColumn      As Long
Dim blnTesting      As Boolean:           blnTesting = True

'setting
Set rgPostDatas = Range(Cells(1, 1), wks.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell))
iLastRow = rgPostDatas.Rows.Count - 1

For i = 2 To iLastRow
  
  'pick each cell / replace some characters
  Set C = rgPostDatas.Cells(i, 3)
  If blnTesting Then C.Select
  sV = C.Value
  iCellRows = UBound(Split(sV, vbLf)) + 1
  
  sArr = Split(sV, vbLf)
  
  For j = 0 To iCellRows - 1
    
    iFoundSpaces = InStr(sArr(j), sSpace)
    
    'filter before doing something
    If iFoundSpaces > 0 Then
      If Not Trim(sArr(j)) = vbNullString Then
      
        'check if there is more space
        For k = iFoundSpaces To Len(sArr(j))
          If Mid(sArr(j), k, 1) = Chr(32) Then
            m = m + 1
          Else
            Exit For
          End If
        Next
      
        'replace the space to get 30 characters like a tab
        iFillSpace = IIf(iFoundSpaces > iTab, 0, iTab - iFoundSpaces)
        sArr(j) = Replace(sArr(j), Space(m), Space(iFillSpace))
        
      End If
    End If
  
    'Clean
    m = 0
    
  Next
  
  'Result: assemble sArr
  If Not Left(sV, 1) = "=" Then C.Value = Join(sArr, vbLf)

Next

'CleanUp
Set C = Nothing

End Sub
```